# Is there anyway to use ALFA to generate XACML without using the Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: xacml, alfa

Is there any way to use ALFA to generate XACML without using the ALFA Eclipse plugin? I would like to create a policy creator and programmatically creating ALFA and converting it to XACML would be preferable to attempting to generate XACML, right?

Answer (score 2):

Not yet but it's on the Axiomatics Roadmap so stay tuned.

### EDIT

As of the latest release, it's now possible